# Executing ToList multiple times in IQueryable

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to fine tune some of the EF code. I could see, that one Iqueryable is converted to list multiple times. Does it mean, EF will execute the query as many times the tolist is invoked (or) will it just execute the query once and will return the same results for the rest of the tolist calls.

Comment: The `IQueryable<>` will be evaluated multiple times, for every time you materialize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IQueryable<> will be evaluated each time you call ToList, so if you have an IQueryable<> in a loop it will be a problem. For example:

```
var first = context.Something;

foreach(var element in first)
{
  var second = context.SomethingElse;
 //do something with second
}

//do something with first again
```

second will be evaluated at least first's length times and first will be evaluated at least twice. So you better move second outside the loop, and force the evaluation using ToList, and you will make sure IQueryable<> will be evaluated just once, like this:

```
var first = context.Something.ToList();
var second = context.SomethingElse.ToList();

foreach(var element in first)
{
 //do something with second
 //second will not be evaluated each iteration
}

//do something with first again
```

Answer (score 1):

> EF will execute the query as many times the tolist is invoked

This is true. By the way for investigation of EF query and how many time It does call to DB - Just use [SQL server Profiler](http://sellsbrothers.com/12698). It's the best approach